# Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:pom:1.3.5.RELEASE

Tags: spring

I am getting the following error while working with `Spring Boot 1.3.5 RELEASE` in *pom.xml*:

```
Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:pom:1.3.5.RELEASE from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:pom:
1.3.5.RELEASE from/to central (): No connector available to access repository central () of type default using the
```

available factories

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751782/error-in-project-creation-in-spring-tool-suite-using-spring-starter-project/39056468#39056468) - it may provide a solution.