# Error in Project creation in Spring Tool Suite using Spring Starter Project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pom.xml, parent-pom

Created an project in Spring Tool Suite using Spring Starter Project and i get an error in pom.xml as below

```
:Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for 
com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.0.RELEASE
from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 
was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted 
until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are
forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.0.RELEASE from/to
central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM.
```

Please help me out in resolving it

Comment: This isn't your error and you don't deserve a downvote. When you created your new project you probably noticed that the External Libraries collection was empty - no Maven. Teh if you right click on your pom.xml file it should give you the option of reimporting Mavin. I tried several times and received a failed download message from Apache every time.Something's going on with the Apache server such that when you try to reimport Mavin you get a message: "Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.0.RELEASE".

Comment: There's more. If you try to go to the url in teh error message - http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 - you get a 404 error.

Comment: I wasted several hours on this and finally just recycled a small POC application I'd written awhile back. There are several other SO posts relating to this same problem. I'll save a link to this page and come back when there's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project name -> select "Run As" -> "Maven Build" then choose your Base Directory and in Goals write "spring-boot:run -U". After that click on Run.

Give it a little time to download all neccessary dependencies and will build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

See my comments above. Yesterday I was able to repeat the problem scenario several times:

After creating a new project with the SPRING INITIALIZR tool the External Libraries folder was empty - no Maven. Looking at the top of the pom file **project** was red squiggly underlined with the mouse-over message "Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.0.RELEASE". I right clicked on project, selected Maven from the dropdown, then selected "reimport". The re-import failed - repeatedly. The external libraries folder remained empty. On a couple of occasions the event log message displayed the Failure to transfer ... message. Other times nothing was logged.

Today I decided to give it another try. ***This time*** I got the same "Failure to transfer ... " message ***but*** the external libraries were added, presumably from the local repository. The project now builds successfully.

Only advice I can offer is the old "*If at first you don't succeed try try again*"

Answer (score 0):

i did exactly what Faisal said and, after download all dependencies, the build occurs

after this (even with the project runing) the eclipse error marker continues on the project folder, so, i just right-click > Maven > Update Project... > OK and all was fixed

thanks!